# How to get ASAN to ignore child process?

Tags: linux, gcc, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to run my application with ASAN enabled to search for leaks and other errors but, since I'm using popen inside the application, sanitizer reports child process errors as well it seems (which I really do not care about and are confusing).

Is there a way to make it ignore child processes ?

My environment is: Fedora 26, gcc 7.3.1, libasan 7.3.1-6

Comment: ASAN cannot possibly do what you say it does. `popen` immediately replaces the forked process with another executable, and unless that executable was built with ASAN, ASAN cannot report anything about it. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you using `LD_PRELOAD`?

Comment: @yugr yes, is that the reason it affects child processes ?

Comment: Even if you preload libasan it should not affect the child process built without -fsanitize=address.

Comment: @n.m. Preloading would still affect them because Asan will detect errors in heap-allocated memory accessed via standard libc APIs. This is due to libc interceptors inside `libasan.so`.

Comment: @yugr this is not what my experience shows. Perhaps it will catch certain class of errors but it didn't catch buffer overflows in malloc'd memory for me.

Comment: @n.m. It will catch buffer overflow done by `memcpy` or `strcpy` (but beware that gcc sometimes "optimizes" them into inline loops and in such cases they will of course not be instrumented).

Comment: @yugr indeed. I wonder why it doesn't catch the problem at `free` time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are using `LD_PRELOAD=libasan.so` which will cause Asan runtime to be preloaded to child processes. This will cause some limited form of sanitization because runtime will intercept and sanitize calls to standard libc functions like `malloc` or `memcpy`.

There is no builtin way to disable this inside Asan so your best bet would be to reset `LD_PRELOAD` at program start:

```
int main() {
# ifdef __SANITIZE_ADDRESS__
  // Do not sanitize child processes
  // TODO: strip only libasan.so, keep everything else
  unsetenv("LD_PRELOAD");
# endif
```

Comment: I ran into a problem with this approach: I *think* that dynamically loaded libraries that are loaded *after* `unsetenv` do not work and even make ASan stop working properly. I found that [ld](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) provides the option to run programs via `--preload` (as of glibc version 2.30), which does not affect child processes, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: @ingomueller.net It's hard to comment without a reprocase but I would be very surprised if `unsetenv` of `LD_PRELOAD` influenced behavior of Asan or any other shlib in the same process.